# unicode error for (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Tags: python

Getting  (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape for Label in tkinter

```
logo = PhotoImage(file ="C:\Users\User\Downloads\algosnc.png"
w = tk.Label(root,image* logo,bg = "#FFFFFF").place(x= 450, y= 5)
w.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

tried replacing\ with / but did not work

Comment: Please fix the syntax errors in your [mre], and add the full exception traceback to your question with an [edit].

Comment: The `\U` sequences in your file name are unicode escape sequences. Either escape them as `\\U` or use a raw string literal.